# git push origin master not pushing the files

Tags: git, git-push

I have setup my remote git and local git on my mac
I was able to create a git repo (git init myrepo) on the remote machine (Linux)
Added few files and committed them no problems (git add , git commit -m "test")

From my local I was able to clone the repo from the remote with no issues (git clone ssh://user@IP/Path)

So far so good no issues.

I have created few files locally and used git add and commit then tried to push them to the remote server using git push origin master

initially I received an error message and searching around the solution was to run this command directly on the remote server:
git config receive.denyCurrentBranch ignore

That fixed the issues and now I am able to push successfully:

`$ git push origin master`

```
git add test.sh 
git add git*
git commit -m "Adding 2 new files and updating test.sh"
[master 4dd11a0] Adding 2 new files and updating test.sh
3 files changed, 109 insertions(+)
create mode 100644 gitHowToUrls.txt
create mode 100644 git_howto.txt
git push origin master
Counting objects: 7, done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (5/5), done.
Writing objects: 100% (5/5), 1.91 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 5 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
To ssh://root@IP/path/myrepo
ad4a8b2..4dd11a0  master -> master
```

`$ git push -u origin master`

```
Branch master set up to track remote branch master from origin.
Everything up-to-date
```

`$ git push origin HEAD:master`

```
Everything up-to-date
```

I even checked to make sure that the files match

`$ git ls-remote origin`

```
52543130bff4f9f37a23b01b0c44c7549ab82dd9        HEAD
52543130bff4f9f37a23b01b0c44c7549ab82dd9        refs/heads/master
```

`$ git ls-remote`

```
From ssh://root@IP/path/myrepo
52543130bff4f9f37a23b01b0c44c7549ab82dd9        HEAD
52543130bff4f9f37a23b01b0c44c7549ab82dd9        refs/heads/master
```

However when I go to my remote repo (root@IP/path/myrepo)
I can't see any of the new files!!! Any idea what I am doing wrong?

I ran git log on the remote server and I see all my notes:

```
root@IP [myrepo]# git log
 commit 52543130bff4f9f37a23b01b0c44c7549ab82dd9
Author: joe d <myemail@myemail>
Date:   Sat Mar 22 15:56:30 2014 -0700

    adding again, since first time didn't work

 commit 4dd11a0235cdabe528f8755253989ce85df4fa8b
Author: joe d <myemail@myemail>
Date:   Sat Mar 22 15:48:08 2014 -0700

    Adding 2 new files and updating test.sh

 commit ad4a8b224989dc2131b6a33f41b95ce8b2a5c96a
Author: joe d <myemail@myemail>
Date:   Sat Mar 22 11:33:34 2014 -0700

   test

 commit 956ff16e081587fa59a8cec73fc383744c5c3a5e
Author: joe d <myemail@myemail>
Date:   Sat Mar 22 18:32:30 2014 +0000

    test
```

My remote repo:

```
root@IP [myrepo]# ls -la
total 20
drwxr-xr-x 4 root    root    4096 Mar 22 18:32 .
drwxr-x--- 6 joe nobody  4096 Mar 22 18:30 ..
drwxr-xr-x 8 root    root    4096 Mar 22 18:38 .git
drwxr-xr-x 2 joe joe 4096 Mar 21 22:12 images
-rw-r--r-- 1 root    root     992 Mar 22 18:31 index.html
```

My local repo:

```
localmachine:myrepo joe$ ls -la
total 32
drwxr-xr-x   8 joe  1668562246   272 Mar 22 16:42 .
drwxr-xr-x   3 joe  1668562246   102 Mar 22 11:33 ..
drwxr-xr-x  15 joe  1668562246   510 Mar 22 16:07 .git
-rw-r--r--   1 joe  1668562246   445 Mar 22 16:42 gitHowToUrls.txt
-rw-r--r--   1 joe  1668562246  3291 Mar 22 15:56 git_howto.txt
-rwxr-xr-x   1 joe  1668562246    81 Mar 22 15:43 test.sh
drwxr-xr-x   6 joe  1668562246   204 Mar 22 11:33 images
-rw-r--r--   1 joe  1668562246   992 Mar 22 11:33 index.html
```

Thanks

NEW NOTE:

OK, so I wasn't using bare branch for sure, I think its the command I ran on the remote system

```
git config receive.denyCurrentBranch ignore
```

I have deleted both repos on local and remote and created it again (No bare for sure)

Then attempted a push like so and received this error:

```
localrepo$ git push origin master
Counting objects: 6, done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (5/5), done.
Writing objects: 100% (5/5), 1.98 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 5 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: error: refusing to update checked out branch: refs/heads/master
remote: error: By default, updating the current branch in a non-bare repository
remote: error: is denied, because it will make the index and work tree inconsistent
remote: error: with what you pushed, and will require 'git reset --hard' to match
remote: error: the work tree to HEAD.
remote: error: 
remote: error: You can set 'receive.denyCurrentBranch' configuration variable to
remote: error: 'ignore' or 'warn' in the remote repository to allow pushing into
remote: error: its current branch; however, this is not recommended unless you
    remote: error: arranged to update its work tree to match what you pushed in some
remote: error: other way.
remote: error: 
remote: error: To squelch this message and still keep the default behaviour, set
remote: error: 'receive.denyCurrentBranch' configuration variable to 'refuse'.
To ssh://root@IP/path/myrepo
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (branch is currently checked out)
error: failed to push some refs to 'ssh://root@IP/path/myrepo'
```

This time round I entered refuse instead of ignore

```
git config receive.denyCurrentBranch refuse
```

Running git push generated a new error message:

```
localRepo$ git push origin master

Counting objects: 6, done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (5/5), done.
Writing objects: 100% (5/5), 1.98 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 5 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: error: refusing to update checked out branch: refs/heads/master
To ssh://root@IP/path/myrepo
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (branch is currently checked out)
error: failed to push some refs to 'ssh://root@IP/path/myrepo'
```

How do I uncheck the branch so I could successfully push from local to remote repo?

Comment: Run `git log` in your remote repo.  Does that match up?  You might be on the wrong branch.

Comment: Did you actually check them out on the remote repo? Is the remote repo 'naked' as most are?

Comment: the remote repo has the original files, the newly added ones are on my local and I thought if I do git add, commit and push they should appear on the remote server, is that not the case? do I Need to run anything on the remote server?

Comment: I just updated 1 file again on my local and confirmed that I see it when running git log on the remote server

Comment: I have edited my answer to address your edited question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are pushing to a non-bare repo (which works because of the `receive.denyCurrentBranch` being set to ignore).

But it it possible that your remote non-bare repo:

- has checked out a different branch than master (and since you are pushing to master, the content of the working tree wouldn't change)
- or has checked out a commit (meaning you are in a [detached HEAD state](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3965714/6309), which you can confirm with a git branch inside that repo, to see if any of those branches is marked as checked out or not).

---

> I have deleted both repos on local and remote and created it again (No bare for sure)

By *default*, `receive.denyCurrentBranch` is set to '`refuse`', so your error messages are consistent with that.

Try setting it on 'ignore', and since your remote repo is on `master`, your push will go through.

**But you won't see any file**: you need a post-receive hook which would checkout your working tree or reset it to HEAD, for the files to actually appear.

See for instance "[Git: making pushes to non-bare repositories safe](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6075584/6309)"

> my post-receive hook looks like this:

```
export GIT_WORK_TREE=..
git checkout -f HEAD
```

---

The [OP](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3451003/user3451003) reports [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22585118/git-push-origin-master-not-pushing-the-files/22585742#comment34385472_22585742):

> the answer to the original issue is run this on the remote server:

```
git config receive.denyCurrentBranch ignore
```

> Then Add `export GIT_WORK_TREE=.. git checkout -f HEAD` To your gitrepo `<PATH>/.git/hooks/post-receive`
>
> That did the trick and I am now able to push files from my local to the remote repo!!!

Comment: Thank you for your update, how do I set the post-receive hook ?
Where do I set it up?

Sorry, as you can see I am a noob and just started with Git today :-(

Comment: @user3451003 then you could consider pushing to a bare repo instead (as in http://stackoverflow.com/a/22576537/6309). But hooks are in your `repo/.git/hooks`: See git hooks http://git-scm.com/docs/githooks.

Comment: Thanks for the update, the answer to the original issue is 
run this on the remote server:  git config receive.denyCurrentBranch ignore

Then Add 
export GIT_WORK_TREE=..
git checkout -f HEAD

To your gitrepo<PATH>/.git/hooks/post-receive

That did the trick and I am now able to push files from my local to the remote repo!!!

Comment: @user3451003 not bad for someone having started Git yesterday ;) But remember, the best practice is to push to a bare repo. See http://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/sitaramc/sitaramc.github.com/blob/dce410b2a2804723676db9cabd7bb506b6d9ba05/concepts/bare.html

Comment: @user3451003 That being said, I have included your solution you mention in your comment in the answer, for more visibility.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably pushing to a [bare repository](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-on-the-Server-Getting-Git-on-a-Server). You must clone it someplace and pull from the remote in order to see live changes.

To create a bare repository at myPath; you'll need to be logged into a shell on myIP:

1. mv myPath myPath2 # saves the live repository
2. git clone --bare myPath2 myPath # creates the bare repository

Now your push should work and follow @VonC's instructions above in configuring your post-receive hook.

Comment: Its not a bare repo, as I only used git init myrepo

Comment: The one you're pushing *to* must be bare.

Comment: I just looked at my history and I only used git init, I will rm -rf the entire folder and recreate it again and see, but I am sure it's not using bare, could this be the issue:

on the remote server: git config receive.denyCurrentBranch ignore

Comment: no, you need to mark ssh://root@IP/path/myrepo as `bare` to push to it.

Comment: just edited my original question with more info, I think its related to git config receive.denyCurrentBranch ignore
Since now I am unable to push

Comment: Make IP:/path/myrepo directory a bare repository, see the edit for the command you need to do this.